# A barometer manufacturer has discovered that one of its cheaper products is faulty. On rainy days, it incorrectly predicted ‘no rain’ 10% of the time.

Tags: probability

A barometer manufacturer has discovered that one of its cheaper products is faulty. On rainy days, it incorrectly predicted ‘no rain’ 10% of the time. On fine days it incorrectly predicted ‘rain’ 30% of the time. In Manchester, it rains 40% of the time. If, on a particular day, one of these barometers predicts ‘rain’, what is the probability that it will actually rain?

My idea is that the probability of rain is 40% and if the barometer predicts 'no rain' for 10%, it's actually raining 90% of the time. So the probability should be $0.9\times 0.4=0.36$. However, it's wrong. I want to know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Bayes' Theorem. Your result is wrong because you have to condition your probability on the total predict rain probability, thus the correct result is

$$\mathbb{P}[\text{Rain}|\text{Predict Rain}]=\frac{0.36}{0.36+0.18}=\frac{2}{3}$$